# How do I keep my chatbot frontend code written in JavaScript constant for every page in my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rasa

I want the bot to be displayed in every page, not only the index. Is there a way to do it automatically or do I manually have to copy the script in every page?

Comment: HI and welcome to SO. I think we will need more detail to give any helpful answer here. Typically you can include scripts and resources in a document. This way you only copy the includes/references instead of a component itself. Or you use some kind of backend or framework that puts the pages together for you. But as I said: Please provide more details on your stack, ideally a [mre]. If in doubt please take the [tour] and read [ask] to get started with this community.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.